# Ubuntu 15.10: Acer laptop freezes when put into standby (won't shut down)

Tags: boot, graphics, fan

I  have a problem running Ubuntu on my new Acer laptop, which is less than a year old. The comp's spec is: Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3530 @ 2.16GHz × 4 Graphics: Intel® Bay Trail Memory 7.7GB.

I had Windows 8, upgraded it to Windows 10 and then partitioned the drive cos I didn't like Windows 10. This was when the crashes started. Yesterday I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10, got same problem, which is:

If I try to go to standby, or shutdown or restart the laptop, then it goes to a black screen and then the fan comes on every 15 seconds or so. This will continue until the battery runs out!  The screen occasionally freezes as well and the fan will start to run every 15 secs then as well. At that point I have to force a restart.

I'm only a beginner on Linux and can't follow the more complex instructions. beyond 'copy and paste' into terminal.I have checked the forums and I think it's a problem with the graphics card, but don't know what to do. Can anyone help, is this a problem with the hardware?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem related to the dw_dmac module. If you open the terminal and enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then add the line

```
blacklist dw_dmac
```

This may or may not work for you.

If you want to be sure, install Ubuntu 12.04. It still has support, hopefully until this bug will be resolved and you should not have any shutdown and hibernation problems whatsoever.

It seems the single chip Atom processors by Intel cause this to happen, may be related to the APU. Possibly a newer kernel (16.04+) could ultimately solve this?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Excuse my ignorance but I pasted those in terminal but then can't 'save' what I've done and leave the terminal, so not sure it worked. I'm downloading Ubuntu 14.04.3 as that has LTS.

Comment: Hello Craig Thomas, you save edits to files in the terminal by pressing Ctrl+O, then accept the overwrite prompt. After that, close the file with Ctrl+X (refer to the bottom of the terminal window when in nano-mode). When copying and pasting lines, make sure to press Shift as well as Ctrl if you are in the terminal window, Ctrl+C actually cancels an operation. ;-) I experienced the same issue as you did and Ubuntu 14.04 did not work for me. You may try it, but in my experience the only version that ran without any issues was 12.04 - which is also LTS and still under support until 2017!

Comment: Hey Prototype, I have the same specs as the person in this post. Your solution helped me with reboot, shutdown issues, thanks you for your answer. However, my computer will suddenly crash hard leaving the screen frozen in time, then the fan starts revving in the 15 mins interval described above. Is this what made you switch back to 12.04? Do you know anything about what I'm facing? Your experience and suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi fbelanger, yes this sounds exactly like it. Actually, I often wasn't even able to install versions above 12.04, because the live system would freeze on boot with the fan spinning periodically without using the acpi=off grub parameter. Unfortunately, I believe I can't be of much help either. I too noticed that blacklisting the dw_dmac module does not seem to work reliably, after a while I got crashes as well (possibly an update of some sort), then I installed 12.04, which does work flawlessly. This all seems to be related to the Intel Atom(N...) SOC CPUs, I believe Core-CPUs aren't affected.

Comment: Continuing: As for suggestions on what to do, if using 12.04 (at least until the support cycle is over next year) is not an option for you and you have no means of reselling your laptop and obtaining a model without an SOC architecture, you may want to try downloading and installing the 16.04-beta now and see if it works. It will be released at the end of this month and you can just update it and will receive the final version then. I want to try this myself, but I can't reinstall my laptop right now. Otherwise, maybe open a thread on ubuntuforums.org and see if they have some suggestions? ;-)